# Running into a error when trying to sum up all the elements in a matrix using a forall loop

Tags: chapel

While trying to add up all the elements in a matrix I keep getting an error when I use a forall loop, it works using a for loop I'm not sure why.

Here is the error:

```
error: illegal lvalue in assignment
```

code:

```
config const size = 10;
var grid : [1..size, 1..size] real;
var sum : real = 0;

//for user input
for i in 1..size do
    for j in 1..size do
        grid[i,j] = read(uint(8));

forall i in 1..size {
    forall j in 1..size {
        sum += grid[i,j]; //error here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is preventing you from data-racing on `sum`. If your code were allowed, multiple iterations of the outer and inner forall-loops would be updating the same variable concurrently without synchronization. So instead the compiler forces `sum` in the loop body to be a read-only snapshot of the outer `sum`. The mechanism for this is called "forall intents". It is discussed in the [online documentation](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/language/spec/data-parallelism.html#forall-intents).

If your intention is to add up all the elements in a matrix, the chpl-erific way to do it is:

`const sum = + reduce grid;`

Other variations on your code are also possible, depending on what you would like to accomplish.

Aside: it is more efficient to have a single forall over the 2-dimensional space, for example:

`forall (i,j) in {1..size,1..size}     //  {1..size,1..size} is a "domain"`

or, better yet:

`forall (i,j) in grid.domain`

Comment: Didn't the compiler's error message also used to talk about the fact that it was a constant shadow variable and point to which variable it was shadowing and/or which statement caused the shadow variable to be inserted?